# "Deprecated" warnings in Xcode - initWithCoordinate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit, deprecated

So I am trying to get the zip code for a particular location with the `MapKit` Framework by following this tutorial. http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/12/22/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0-part-2/

In

```
MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord];
```

Xcode poses a warning that `initWithCoordinate` is deprecated.

Can anyone tell me what I should be doing ?

Comment: Check the documentation, it usually states which method(s) should be used instead.

Comment: I am right now checking the documentation. There is no reference to alternate methods.

Comment: @johnnieb - Interestingly, the docs do not show `initWithCoordinate:`  as being deprecated, and shows it as "Available in iOS 3.0 and later." [MKReverseGeocoder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323)

Comment: Check the documentation of the SDK you're using (5.0 beta, I presume).

Comment: Got it guys. It's provided in the documentation for iOS5 Beta.

Comment: I'd suggest watching this years WWDC video sessions concerning location services. I think it'll explain a lot...

Comment: lol. yes buddy. My bad. It just did not hit my mind that this is in iOS5 Beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MKReverseGeocoder can be used as you've written from iOS 3.0 and above, as stated [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008323). Check the beta documentation to see if that's still applicable, if you're developing using the iOS5 beta.

Comment: oh crap. Did they change the `MKReverseGeocoder` documentation for iOS5Beta ?

Comment: Anything related to beta can't be discussed under the NDA. Please head over to the developer site for the latest documentation.

Comment: oh crap. Got it. I found the alternate class for it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

This class is deprecated since iOS 5.0. Use the **CLGeocoder** class instead.

if you are supporting previous versions of iOS, check for the existence of the CLGeocoder class using

```
Class geocoder = NSClassFromString(@"CLGeocoder");
if (geocoder != nil){
    theGeocoder = [[geocoder alloc]init];
} else {
    // use MKReverseGeocoder
}
```